# adding customized text to excel "date time picker" control

Tags: excel, datetimepicker, vba

I have an Excel sheet with the 'Microsoft date time picker control'.

The content in the control, by default, when the sheet initializes is the current date.

I wish to display some text in the control when the control is first initialized...something like "Please select a date".

Can this be done? If yes, how? Do we use a macro? Can we modify a property through code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible (and not advisable). The `Value` property is of type date-time.

Comment: Do you know of some other possible way to achieve this? say by using some other date time picker control? Also, can we add/modify the value property to support text? any work around? Because I want the user to pick a date atleast once and not ignore the date input field.

Comment: you could set a strange date, like 01/01/1900 and at the OK button press check if the user changed it, and if not show an error message.

Comment: hmm...yes that is a work around I had contemplated. alright...thanks!